# Socket.io reconnect on disconnect?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Is something like this possible?

```
socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('disconnected...');
    socket.connect();
    socket.on('connect', function(){
    console.log('...reconnected');
    })  
})
```

Comment: Most likely you already have an on "connect" event outside of disconnect so make sure not to duplicate the event.

Comment: Yes, I do, just added it for the purpose of this question. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Socket.io reconnects automatically (if you set the `reconnect` option, although it defaults to true), so you don't really need to do that.

Furthermore, there is a `reconnect` event which seems far more appropriate.

Also, set your event handlers independently, don't set the connect handler in the execution of the disconnect handler.

Comment: Is it the case though if you are cleanly disconnected by the server ? I think not