# AngularJS: Reconnect WebSocket inside a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sockets, service, websocket

Im using web sockets in my AngularJS application.
When a user logs out the web socket connection is closed by the client. 
I need to reconnect the web socket when the user logs back on. 
The web socket is contained within a service (code is simplified a bit):

```
angular.module('myApp').factory("SubscriptionFactory", function () {
    var Service = {};
    var ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8000");

    /* WS methods (onopen, onmessage ect) left out for simplicity */

    Service.reestablishConnection = function() {
        // Reestablishing connection
        ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8000");
    }
    return Service;
```

The problem is that the new instance of the web socket does not work.
 
According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13797262/how-to-reconnect-to-websocket-after-close-connection) the web socket needs to reattach its handlers to the object when its recreated. 
But a AngularJS service is a singleton (and should stay a singleton according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626075/non-singleton-services-in-angular)).
How can I recreate the web socket instance inside my AngularJS singleton service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself. It was actually pretty simple:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory("SubscriptionFactory", function () {
    var Service = {};
    var ws;

    Service.onMessage = function(message) { /* some code */};
    Service.onClose = function() { /* some code */ };
    Service.onOpen = function() { /* some code */};
    Service.onError = function(error) { /* some code */};

    Service.connect = function() {
        // (Re)connect
        ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8000");
        // Reattaching handlers to object
        ws.onmessage = Service.onMessage;
        ws.onclose = Service.onClose;
        ws.onopen = Service.onOpen;
        ws.onerror = Service.onError;
    }
    return Service;
```

What happens here is simple: Im creating a new Web Socket object and manually attaching the Web Sockets handlers to my AngularJS service.