# Websocket stops receiving data after some time (20-30 minutes)

Tags: java, websocket

I am having websocket in java which sends few message (5 -10) every second  to javascript websocket client which then displays using angular ui-grid.

The problem is that after 20-30 minutes, the browser(IE,Firefox, chrome) stops receiving the messages.

- What can be the issue?
- What is the default session timeout value for javax.websocket.Session?
- What settings/values should I check for e.g. `getMaxTextMessageBufferSize()` etc.

Comment: c++ application ,which sends messages, runs on separate server & java application server, which contains the java websocket, runs on separate server. when client(browser) is run from same server (java/tomcat) there is no issue. But if browser is run from different machine the issue arises, the java websocket session is closed with NORMAL_CLOSURE. The issue seems to be packet dropping. Please edit the question to add this info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with communication link ( wire connectivity). I resolved the issue by reconnecting to websocket on websocket.onclose (client side javascript code). The onclose is called when websocket session is closed. I reconnect by calling connect() function inside onclose.

This answer also helped a lot.
[AngularJS: Reconnect WebSocket inside a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32476334/angularjs-reconnect-websocket-inside-a-service)

Answer (score 0):

Check out if getMaxIdleTimeout() / setMaxIdleTimeout() is what you're looking for.

From the javax.websocket.Session docs on setMaxIdleTimeout():

> Set the non-zero number of milliseconds before this session will be closed by the container if it is inactive, ie no messages are either sent or received. A value that is 0 or negative indicates the session will never timeout due to inactivity.

Comment: This may not be required as session is never idle, there are few messages send per every second. Anyway now I am setting setMaxIdleTimeout to zero.