# Blazor on Azure - Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: WebSocket closed with status code: 1006 (no reason given).'

Tags: azure, websocket, entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side

I am getting this connection websocket error when running my blazor app on azure.
This happens roughly 3 to 4 min while doing some database manipulation.
The app is running a script getting info saving info etc. Via EF Core DBContext.
I have found many posts on here that vaguely relate to this but nothing is helping.
The azure app is quite standard, from a Visual Studio "publish" to azure deployment.
The only small change is that i enabled WebSockets. Otherwise setting are default.
It feels like it has to be some azure setting, but i don't know what.
Needless to say it works fine locally. I can run the app for 30-40 min doing the data work accessing a remote azure server.

Sometimes, it actually crashes the azure app completely. and i have to go to the portal and restart it. Not always though sometimes a refresh fixes it. Well, does not fix it for another 3 min or so.

Comment: network in the cloud is not reliable. You should reopen the connection when it drops.

Comment: Keep DbContext instances open only as long as they are needed for an operation, then dispose them. This sounds like a case where you have a long-lived DbContext instance open between operations.

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio how would i do that?

Comment: @StevePy yes, i do, as explained above its a complex script that collects data, manipulates it and saves it back. It usually runs 30 to 40 min.

Comment: try those: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13797262/how-to-reconnect-to-websocket-after-close-connection